# How can I implement this condition with regex?

Tags: java, regex

With regex in java, how do one put condition, i.e. if-then-else? Clearly say, I want to put condition `if "http" exist, "www" CAN exist` or `if "http" doesnot exist "www" HAVE TO exist` in the string. How can I implement that condition with regex?

What I done

```
      ((http){0,1}|(www){0,1})
```

But this is not work

example input :

- if string starts with "http" after it, "www" can come.

  *ex:* **"httpwww < sometext >"**   *--->should be matched*

  *ex:* **"http < sometext >"**    *--->should be matched*
- if string didnot start with "http", string **have to** start with "www"

  *ex:* **"www < sometext >"** *--->should be matched*

  *ex:* **"< sometext >"** *----> should not be matched by regex because it did not started with nor http and www*

Comment: So you want to check if a string starts with either http or www, correct?

Comment: Your second point and your last test case is contradicting.

Comment: @Unihedron which one I dont understand.

Comment: @Antony "_if string didnot start with "http", string have to start with "www"_". In `www`, it did not start with `http`, but did start with `www` (itself)!

Comment: Now that you've edited to clarify, I rolled-back my solution. My old answer did work what you wanted, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple regex match:

```
boolean matches = myString.matches("^(?:http|www).*");
// The .* is for Java implementation
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dW7jJ0/3)!

Comment: your regex means one of the "http" or "www" can exist or both of them. However, there is no __have to__ relation. IF I downvote, I will use it for you

Comment: @Antony - Simply put, your question boils down to - *does my regex start with either http or www*. right?.

Comment: Why the `?:` non-capturing group?

Comment: @TheLostMind The Java implementation incurs processing time writing each backreference location and match for each capturing group match. Hence for Java Regexes, I use capturing groups sparingly. YMMV due to JIT compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic solution for that would be to use "look around"s, as specified in comments.

You can also use an actual `URL` object to do that if, as I imagine, you're working with actual URLs.

For instance:

```
String[] input = { "http://www.google.com", "http://foo.com", "www.foo.com" };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=http).*(?=www)");
for (String s : input) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.printf("Found in %s? %b%n", s, m.find());
    try {
        URL u = new URL(s);

        System.out.printf("Authority starts with www and protocol is http for %s? %b%n", s,
                u.getAuthority().startsWith("www") && u.getProtocol().equals("http"));
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        System.out.printf("%s is not interpreted as well-formed URL.%n", s);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Found in http://www.google.com? true
Authority starts with www and protocol is http for http://www.google.com? true
Found in http://foo.com? false
Authority starts with www and protocol is http for http://foo.com? false
Found in www.foo.com? false
www.foo.com is not interpreted as well-formed URL.
```

Comment: no I have said before, if it starts with "http" after it "www" can come. But second output is false, it should be true. Wait I will add some input

Comment: @Antony take a look at my answer. It should cover your examples.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, your String *should* start with either `http` or `www`.
You don't care if http is followed by www. All you care about is your string should *always* start with *http8 or *www* and nothing else.
So,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "http://www.google.com";
    String s2 = "www.google.com";
    String s3 = "sdfwww.google.com";
    System.out.println(s1.matches("^(http|www).*"));
    System.out.println(s2.matches("^(http|www).*"));
    System.out.println(s3.matches("^(http|www).*"));

}
```

O/P ::

```
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Demo,

```
http://regex101.com/r/dW7jJ0/3
```

Regex is

```
^(httpwww|http|www)
```